# Regression coefficients interpretation

Tags: regression

Can anyone help me with finding out the computations for reaching this conclusion?

"In terms of magnitude, the point estimate implies that going from the average of 8% blacks in the same-gender cohort to 10% (an increase of around 1 within-school standard deviation) would increase the probability of dating a black person by approximately 0.6 percentage points, which is 13% of the mean"

The paper is:[image] Merlino, L. P., Steinhardt, M. F., & Wren-Lewis, L. (2019). More than just friends? School peers and adult interracial relationships. Journal of Labor Economics, 37(3), 663-713.

Comment: In my opinion, you're looking at fixed effects estimation, which means you control for variation between variables to estimate within-variable effects. However, from the information you've given, I'm unable to glean much more. Maybe adding a bit more context, such as describing your variables, might help.